# Vue 3 The template root requires exactly one element. eslint-plugin-vue

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

After scaffolding a Vue 3 project I noticed an error in my App.vue.

```
A functional component that renders the matched component for the given path. Components rendered in can also contain its own , which will render components for nested paths.

API Reference

[vue/no-multiple-template-root]
The template root requires exactly one element.eslint-plugin-vue
```

I tried putting

```
"vue/no-multiple-template-root": 0
```

in my .eslintrc.js

But the error remains. How can I get rid of the error? Since in Vue 3 you don't have to have exactly one element in a template.

```
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    env: {
        node: true
    },
    extends: [
        "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
        "eslint:recommended",
        "@vue/typescript/recommended",
        "@vue/prettier",
        "@vue/prettier/@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2020
    },
    rules: {
        "no-console": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "warn" : "off",
        "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "warn" : "off",
        "vue/no-multiple-template-root": 0
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you add the complete `.eslintrc.js` here please.

Comment: I added the .eslintrc.js

Comment: Hm, this type of error never really occurs for me. The only differences I can see (compared to my settings), are the `extends` part. I'm using the standard linter, and you seem to be using Prettier. Those are everything I'm extending: `plugin:vue/vue3-essential`, `@vue/standard`, `@vue/typescript/recommended` and they never cause me any issue so far.

Comment: For me, the problem wasn't in eslint particularly. I had opened a folder with many projects in it. In this way, eslint was confused about the validation. [Here](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/1297#issuecomment-705988365) is the github issue.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I ended up turning off Vetur linting. Vetur thinks that it is a Vue 2 project becuase it is in a VS  Code workspace.

https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/2299#issuecomment-696015374

You can solve this by doing

```
F1>Preferences:Open Settings (JSON)
```

paste

```
"vetur.validation.template": false,
"vetur.validation.script": false,
"vetur.validation.style": false,
```

Comment: While this definitely works, I'd love to understand exactly what I've just turned off. I also only really required setting venture...template to false. This leaves me wondering why you also suggested turning off script and style. Care to explain? Thanks for the insight.

Comment: BEFORE YOU DO THIS, did you make sure you have only 1 parent tag in the template?
Don't forget to put <router-view /> INSIDE the parent tag.

Answer (score 47):

The error occurred with me, because I had not opened the project root in VS Code, but the parent folder, and Vetur thus looked in this for the `package.json`.

Comment: This answer may sound silly, but it isn't! This trick worked for me than others. Upvoted!!!

Comment: Same here. Upvoted. Didn't even need to change package.json, or add an .eslintrc.js file to the project

Comment: Thanks! That works for me as well.

Comment: Yep, you were right, I was one directory above the project folder!
Tanks!

Comment: Upvoted, this should be the accepted answer. Worked for me as well...

Comment: This was the reason for me as well lol

Comment: Worked as a charm... upvoted

Comment: Silly but worked as charm.

Answer (score 20):

If you are working on a monorepo and thus the package.json is not at the workspace root, then Vetur by default won't able to find package.json, thus it couldn't figure out the vue version.

In that case, we need to tell Vetur the package.json location

https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/guide/setup.html#advanced

[image]

Comment: This is the best solution instead of disabling Vetur, thank you for sharing! A simple `module.exports = { projects: [ './path/to/vue3project' ] }` was enough for me.

Answer (score 20):

Here worked with this:

in .eslintrc.js

instead of:

```
rules: { "vue/no-multiple-template-root": 0 }
```

try:

```
rules: {"vue/no-multiple-template-root": "off" }
```

Comment: if you built your vue project with vue CLI you have a rules section in package.json, that's where this has to go.

Comment: The first option worked for me, +1

Answer (score 14):

Disable Vetur and use [Volar](https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar) instead. It's now the official recommendation for Vue 3 projects.

From the official migration [guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/introduction.html#ide-support):

> It is recommended to use VSCode with our official extension Volar (opens new window), which provides comprehensive IDE support for Vue 3.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Best answer yet. Vetur's "use eslint-plugin-vue" for templates option appears to be non-functional

Comment: This is the way

Answer (score 8):

With `vue create project` on Vue3, add this to your `package.json` file:

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {
      "vue/no-multiple-template-root": "off"
    }
  }
```

Adding the "rules" eliminates the error as described in the question. No need to change the default vetur settings.

Comment: After a VS Code restart, this solved the issue for me!

Answer (score 3):

in .eslintrc.js

rules: {
"vue/valid-template-root": "off"
}

Comment: Doesn't work. I've tried this. Also tried:
rules: {"vue/no-multiple-template-root": "off" }

Comment: @Ryan try to update plugin:vue/essential and eslint:recommended. update your vue ts extension if yo use. I don't have any other special setups and it's works. [setup](https://github.com/robert8888/portfolio/blob/master/components_src/.eslintrc.js).

Answer (score 2):

Penny Liu and skalta has the real answer for Vue 3 projects created by the Vue-cli. Problem is the package.json has to be in the immediate path, not in the child folders.

As the package.json specified the Vue3 extends below, vscode/vetur will read the configs and the error will go away. Adding `"vue/no-multiple-template-root": "off"` won't help as the package.json is not even read by the linter.

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "@vue/standard"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of working in Vue2, it can be fixed as [@mikseros suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71077099/3404438) mentioned, by wrapping my html code in only one `<div>`.

This will trigger the warning:

```html
 <template>
   <div class="first child"> </div>
   <div class="second child"> </div>
 </template>
```

This will fix it:

```html
 <template>
   <div>
      <div class="first child"> </div>
      <div class="second child"> </div>
   </div>
 </template>
```

This is also very common in JSX when working in React.

Answer (score 1):

i have this problem when i first install vue 3

the problem comes from vetur extension

here is the solution

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem, because the vetur extension. Fixed it by turning it off for my template linting only in `settings.json`.

```
"vetur.validation.template": false
```

If you want to turn off in your specific workspace you could create a `.vscode` folder in your root folder, and create a new file `settings.json` inside the `.vscode` then paste the code above to your `settings.json`

and reload your vscode by typing `ctrl+shift+p` and then typing `Reload Window` and enter, the error should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the best solution for that is to wrap all elements in the template into one div element. It works perfectly for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Downvoted because Vue 3 allows multiple roots, and is precisely what the OP wants to use

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I've scaffolded vue3 app in subdirectory within my project's workspace. If you don't have any `package.json` in your project's root directory, vetur can't understand which version of vue.js you're using and assumes it is less then `2.5`. If the version is wrong, you will get wrong template validation.

So, to overcome this problem you'll need to create a `vetur.config.js` in the root of your workspace, and provide information about where to find your vue3 app. The following is an example of my setup:

```
module.exports = {
  projects: [
    './website',
  ],
}
```

You can learn more in vetur docs:
https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/reference/#example
https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/guide/FAQ.html#vetur-can-t-find-tsconfig-json-jsconfig-json-in-xxxx-xxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

The solution worked for me to disable the setting in vetur
!([settings - extentions - vetur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwOYp.png))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Just try to wrap in `<div>` tag, It worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

The main reason behind getting this error is that your project is inside of a folder.

Just remove it from the folder. Your project must be inside of one folder only.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

**For anyone coming at later time who wants to actually *fix* the issue rather than disabling this features.**

It simply means you have more than one element in your `<template>` in any of your `.vue` files.

For example you have this:

```
<template>
  <div class="first">
      SOMETHING HERE
  </div>
  <div class="second">
      SOMETHING HERE AS WELL
  </div>
</template>
```

Notice that there are two elements in in `<template>`, so to fix this issue you can simply add everything in a parent `<div>`. Because there should only be one element in `<template>`.

For above Example do this:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="first">
            SOMETHING HERE
        </div>
        <div class="second">
            SOMETHING HERE AS WELL
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

This would fix the issue.

Comment: That isn't a "fix". Vue 3 supports multiple root components, so this isn't an issue with the way the template is written.
It's a linting issue and the other answers are more correct, especially the one about ensuring VS Code is opened at the root of the project and not any parent directory outside of it.

Answer (score -4):

Check

```
 vscode-> plugins-> close Vetur
```

and restart vscode, then open Vetur.

For more informations, check linke below:
https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/1297#issuecomment-755202013