# Problem "vue/no-multiple-template-root" occurs, how do I fix it?

Tags: vue.js, eslint-plugin-vue

**Edit: Somehow doing v-if and v-else statements fixed this. Nonetheless could someone explain how to fix this?**

Summary: Error occurs because of 2  Elements present in template. This [Vue 3 The template root requires exactly one element.eslint-plugin-vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64867504/vue-3-the-template-root-requires-exactly-one-element-eslint-plugin-vue) isn't helping. How do I fix this?

I'm currently following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72Fk9i9HcZM&t=830s) to create a Chat with Vue and Firebase. In the tutorial having two div-Elements is working w/o any issues. However, I tried it and it works but it is underlined in red and I ran into some issues later on. This is the Description of said problem:

*[vue/no-multiple-template-root]
The template root requires exactly one element.eslint-plugin-vue*

I searched for some solutions and found this [Vue 3 The template root requires exactly one element.eslint-plugin-vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64867504/vue-3-the-template-root-requires-exactly-one-element-eslint-plugin-vue). I tried the solutions provided but it doesn't solve the Problem.

This is my first time working with vue and eslint and I'm a beginner at programming. Could someone help me please?

Comment: Please note that building a chat app with Vuex and Firebase is difficult even for experienced programmers. I see you've set yourself up with the entire dev stack (webpack/vue-cli/eslint), these are complex tools and require a considerable amount of time to truely master. I'd highly recommend to play with Vue inside a regular HTML document without external tools, get to know to building blocks of a vue application, learn how much fun Vue could be. Good luck on your journey!

Comment: What worked for me in VSCode https://stackoverflow.com/a/64901711/1821558

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vue 2 it was not allowed to have more than one root node inside a template.

So this was allowed:

```
<template>
   <div> <!--- this is a root node -->
       <p>This is content</p>
       <p>This is more content</p>
   </div>
</template>
```

But this is not allowed:

```
<template>
   <div> <!--- this is a root node -->
       <p>This is content</p>
       <p>This is more content</p>
   </div>
   <div> <!-- error: this is a second root node -->
      <p> .... </p>
   </div>
</template>
```

You get a white screen and bells and whistles will go off in Developer Console if you do that.

There was one exception though for root nodes that have v-if, v-else, v-else-if. The reasoning behind this is that, after evaluating these if statements there will be one only node that is mounted. This may be confusing to new users.

So, to make it clear, this is allowed:

```
<template>
   <div v-if="someExpression">
      <p>Case 1</p>
   </div>
   <div v-else-if="somethingElse">
     <p>Some other case</p>
   </div>
   <div v-else>
     <p>Else case</p>
   </div>
</template>
```

Vue 3 does allow muliple root nodes, so maybe your eslint rules are still vue 2 rules. Either way. For Vue it was recommended to always wrap the entire thing in  tags just to be sure.

Multiple root node errors are often caused by forgetting to properly close html tags, or use the wrong ones.

Comment: Thank you so much. This explains it

Answer (score 1):

the simplest and most `ingenious` way is wrap all the code in a single parent div.

```
`<template>
    <div class="main-div>
      *<!--------all your code should be in here------->*
    </div>
</template>`
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is invalidate this rule，try this in your `.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    rules: {
        'vue/no-multiple-template-root': 'off'
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this in package.json:

```
"eslintConfig": {
 "rules": "vue/valid-template-root": 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you for translating your post.  Do read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand, please. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.