# vue3: instant prototyping multiple root elements

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I try to use instant prototyping in Vue3, having installed `@vue/cli` and `@vue/cli-service-global`, got this error:

```
Failed to compile.

./Alert.vue
Module Error (from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/eslint-    loader/index.js):

/home/xrfang/git/deployer/gui/src/components/Alert.vue
5:3  error  The template root requires exactly one element  vue/no-multiple-template-root

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

As far as I know "template root requires exactly one element" is a requirement in Vue2, Vue3 should allow multiple root elements in one template?

Comment: You are correct and it works in my setup with Vue3. You might be using some older version of the vue compiler. Vue3 must still be installed with `@next`.

Comment: I am pretty sure that I only have vue3 installed. how to verify that with npm?

Comment: It seems like the ESLint configuration might be the problem. The rule `vue/no-multiple-template-root` is part of the rulesets "plugin:vue/essential", "plugin:vue/strongly-recommended" and "plugin:vue/recommended". See https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-multiple-template-root.html Do you have one of these rulesets in your ESLint config? You can swap them with "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended" and/or "plugin:vue/vue3-strongly-recommended"

Comment: I used eslint config generated by vue create. To be honest, I am still learning vue3, having no idea how to customize eslint config. If what you said is the cause, I would say this is a bug in the vue-cli tool.

Comment: What version is your globally installed `vue` which you used for the installation? `vue --version`

Comment: @vue/cli 4.5.11   @ssc-hrep3

Comment: this should solve your error. Follow the steps in the guide: https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/guide/linting-error.html#linting

Answer (score 0):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66929449/1459653) suggests, wrap all the code inside the template tags in a single parent div.

Otherwise, to simply stop the error form displaying, Visual Studio Code (VSC) users can do the following:

- Open "extensions" in VSC
- Find and open "Vetur" extension by Pine Wu
- Click the gear and select "extension settings"
- Scroll down to "Vetur > Validation: Template" and uncheck the box

*This is built upon @wittgenstein's comment above to "follow the steps in the guide: [vuejs.github.io/vetur/guide/linting-error.html#linting](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/guide/linting-error.html#linting)*"

*This worked for me, but **beware** that I'm a novice and it's possible there are drawbacks to the above that I'm not aware of.*